# When does a javascript function is being executed in a jquery mobile page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a php function that, after it did his computations, contains this code:

```
echo("<script> window.location.replace('index.php#login'); </script>");
```

meant to redirect the page to another, under certain circumstances. The function works, the javascript code works, but if fails in one case. If i write *manually* the address of the page the javascript part of the code seems not to be executed, while if i manually reload the page (for example using the reload button in firefox) works like a charm.

The php function is being executed, with his redirect code, at the beginning of the page index.php in the head section. The page index php is a jquery mobile page, that include every other page of the site, so if i want to call a page, i have to write an address like site.com/index.php#nameOfThePage. The problem happen when i am, for example on a page site.com/index.php#Page1 and i call another Page manually deleting from the address the part "Page1" and writing, for instance, "Page2". Instead, if i reload, the script is being correctly executed.

So the question is: when does a javascript function is being executed in a jquery mobile page? What i have to do to make the function works in every way, even manually, a page is called?

EDIT: the problem happens in firefox e safari, while with chrome the code works in every case...

Comment: Use JQM events for this.

Comment: I don't really know what jqm event are, but i cannot use javascript to do the same, for the php function does a control on the database which i can't do with javascript. (or not?)

Comment: when you echo `script` this way, it wont be executed. If you want to change between pages, use `$.mobile.changePage()` function.

Comment: oki, but this must be used inside a document.ready etc etc. I need to change page at the end of a php function that verify something on the database and decide whether to change page or not.